# Xamarin VS2013 ERROR: Could not find the selected device

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I'm trying to get a list of Devices Attached in the Device combo box, but it won't show a list somehow. I just did a fresh install of Xamarin on a new system with VS2013 sp2.

I've attached to the build host without issue and my Mac is up to date with 7.XX.

However, I've received these errors when trying run debug on the t-shirt app 
(https://xamarin.com/sharp-shirt)

Error   1   Failed to change active application on server   Xamarin.iOS Extension 0

Error   2   ERROR: Could not find the selected device
Available devices:
iPhone (Retina) 7.0
iPad 7.0
iPad (Retina) 7.0

Try to refresh the device list with the Refresh button
        0   0

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You must change the CPU mode to IPhoneSimulator and the list fill with the correct devices.

[image]